# Can Desoldered Solder Be Still Handy?

Tags: soldering

Sorry for amateur and maybe "cheap ass" question, but i was thinking if desoldered solder can still be useful. Can it?

Answer (score 18):

This sounds like a lot more trouble than it's worth, and probably not even a savings.  Heated solder will have partially oxidized and it's flux will be gone.  I suppose if you melt it the oxidized part will float to the top and you can add your own flux, but unless you are a large commerical operation using lots of solder I really don't see this being worth it.

I am having a hard time imagining how you'd even collect the used solder in a hobby situation.  We have several people here doing electrical engineering and technician work professionally, yet this would make no sense here whatsoever.  Used solder would come drops or tiny balls at a time as the irons are tinned or components desoldered from a thru hole board and the holes cleared.  If I tried to collect the tiny balls of solder, I'd probably scoop up as much dirt and other stuff like clipped leads as I would solder.  A whole role of 60/40 rosin core solder may take a year or more to go thru, so even if all of it could be reclaimed it would be a tiny savings.  Just the wasted time dealing with reclaiming solder wouldn't be worth it.  And then there are the questions about the resulting quality and the extra energy required to melt it down.  No thanks.

Even if you could do all this successfully and somehow profitably, then how would you use the solder?  At best you have a small molten pool in a solder pot.  That's very different from wire solder with flux core.  For the ordinary hobbyist or small scale user, a pool of molten solder is not much use.  We don't have a solder pot here, for example.  I'd get one if there was a good reason for it, but so far that hasn't come up.

Frankly, this sounds like a really silly idea for small guys like hobbyists and even us.

Answer (score 8):

The solder won't have the flux you usually have in solder wire. One of the flux's functions is to break the surface tension of the solder, so that it doesn't form blobs instead of flowing over the surface. A second reason for using flux is that at high temperatures it reduces (inverse of oxidation) any oxides on the surface which has to be soldered, thus allowing for better penetration of the solder = better solder joints.
You can try soldering without flux, but results may be poor.

Comment: you can also add your own flux on the joints

Comment: @Nate: You can, but that's a pain (there's a reason rosin core flux was invented and is so popular), and I still don't understand how you intend to get the melted solder from the solder pot to a joint on a PC board for soldering on a individual component.  Unless you're just tinning leads or do wave soldering, how is this useful?

Comment: I agree, electronics soldering wouldn't be very practical. the only way to efficiently solder with the recycled material would be to make basically a glue gun that dispenses solder. Basically, impractical (unless somebody can think of a way to spin the recycled solder back into wire ;). The best use for the recycled solder would probably be plumbing joints

Comment: @Nate: Note that solder with lead in it shouldn't be used in plumbing on the supply side.

Comment: @OlinLathrop definetly! only use RoHS compliant stuff or tin for supply lines

Answer (score 6):

Funny you should ask.  I have been pondering the same question, as I have recently been doing quite a lot of component recovery from old boards, and have built up quite a lot of used solder.

I am pondering investing in a "solder pot" which is ideal for tinning wires etc:

[image]

Just popping the used solder in there to melt down with the rest should be doable.